# Change runtime from Python to Go in App Engine standard environment

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python, google-app-engine-go

I have a website on AppEngine that is 99% static. It is running on Python 2.7 runtime. Now the time has come to evolve this webapp, and since I have almost none Python code in it, I'd prefer to write it in Go instead.

**Can I change runtime from Python 2.7 to Go, while keeping the project intact?** Specifically, I want to keep the same app-ID, the same custom domain attached to it, the same SSL certificate, and so on.

**What do I have to do in order to do that?** I surely have to change `runtime` in the `app.yaml`. Is there anything else?

Bonus question: will such change happen without a downtime?

I'd be grateful for any links to documentation on exactly that (swapping runtime on a live app). I can't find any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GAE services offer complete [code isolation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/microservices-on-app-engine#service_isolation). So it *should* be possible to simply deploy a new version of the service, which can be written in a different language or even use a different GAE (standard/flex) environment. Personally I didn't go through a language change, but I did go through a split of a single-service app into a multi-service one, I see no reason for which the same principles wouldn't apply.

Maybe develop the new version as a separate app first, to be able to test it properly without risking an accidental impact on the old version and only after that bring the code as a new version in the old app. That'd be using the GAE [project isolation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/microservices-on-app-engine#project_isolation). You can, in fact, test the entire version migration as a separate app if you so desire without even touching the existing app. I am using this technique - a separate app ID - to implement a staging environment for my app, completely isolated from my production app, see [How to copy / clone entire Google App Engine Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45165490/how-to-copy-clone-entire-google-app-engine-project/45172589#45172589)

Make sure to not switch traffic to the new version at deployment time. This keeps the app working with the old version. Test first that the new version works as expected using [Targeted routing](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/how-requests-are-routed#targeted_routing). Then maybe use [Splitting traffic across multiple versions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/splitting-traffic#splitting_traffic_across_multiple_versions) to perform A/B testing with just a small percentage of the traffic going to the new version. Finally, when happy with the results, switch all traffic to the new version.

You need to pay special attention to the app-level configs (dispatch, cron, queue, datastore indexes), shared by all services/versions. They need to be functionally equivalent in the 2 versions. The service isolation doesn't apply to them, only project isolation can ensure no impact to the old version.

There *should* be no need to make any change to the app ID, custom domain mapping or SSL config. The above mentioned tests should confirm that.

A few potentially interesting posts related to re-working services/modules:

- [Converting App Engine frontend versions to modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32038996/converting-app-engine-frontend-versions-to-modules/32042415#32042415)
- [Google App Engine upgrading part by part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33993600/google-app-engine-upgrading-part-by-part/34001871#34001871)
- [Migrating to app engine modules, test versions first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32407006/migrating-to-app-engine-modules-test-versions-first/32425296#32425296)
- [Advantages of implementing CI/CD environments at GAE project/app level vs service/module level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43218971/advantages-of-implementing-ci-cd-environments-at-gae-project-app-level-vs-servic)

Answer (score 4):

Specify a `runtime` as well as a new value for `version`.  When deployed you'll have an older version that is Python and a newer version that is Go.  There won't be any downtime (same as when deploying a newer version of Python).

Rather than trusting links/docs (that may be out of date or not 100% exactly what you're trying to do), why not create a new GAE-Std project for testing purposes and try it yourself.  Having a GAE-Std test project is good for testing new function (especially by other testers who won't have access to the dev environ on your laptop).